# Error decimal in R

Tags: r, decimal

I'm working with one dataset that has a numeric variable with two decimal. When I read the dataset it shows that variable with the decimals, but any analysis that the results do not show the decimal.

Eg.

```
 dados <- read.csv("BANCO.csv",dec=",", sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

 dput(dados) 

 structure(list(VAR = c("PJ", "PJ", "PF", "PF", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ",  
 "PF", "PJ", "PJ", "PF", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ"), Saldo = c(99514,04, 
 49781,73, 49731,17, 49723,11, 398253,84, 49805,66, 49764,19,  
 100363,2, 49739,54, 99580,98, 49781,73, 198958,16, 49739,54, 
 49830,54)), .Names = c("VAR", "Saldo"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  
 -14L)) 

 > summary(dados) 

      VAR                      
  Length:14              
  Class :character      
  Mode  :character     

 Saldo 
 Min.   : 49723   
 1st Qu.: 49746  
 Median : 49794 
 Mean   : 96040   
 3rd Qu.: 99564   
 Max.   :398254   

 > tapply(dados$Saldo, list(VAR=dados$VAR), sum, na.rm=TRUE) 

 VAR 

 PF 6111262   
 PJ 82400812
```

Comment: Can we see the first few lines of the file you're trying to import?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem with the float separating symbol. Try to change "," to "." and everything should work.